# try/except in list comprehension

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to convert the following into a list comprehension?

```
cleaned_list = []
for item in dirtry_list:
    try:
        item.video
    except Video.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    else:
        cleaned_list.append(item)
```

Comment: No doubt there is a convoluted list comprehension that would replicate this, but why would you want to change from the above?

Comment: Surely the 'filter' function in python is the right paradigm for creating a clean list from a dirty list? clean = filter(function,dirty). Then just write your function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since, based on your other questions, you're using Django, just check the [actual field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#database-representation).

```
cleaned_list = [item for item in dirty_list if item.video_id is not None]
```

Comment: `cleaned_list = [item for item in dirty_list if not item.video_id]`?

Comment: @MFB: Under the condition that no ID can be 0, yes.

Answer (score 15):

You cannot put a `try:`statement in a list comprehension. [Generators](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators) exist for more complex list processing:

```
def clean(lst):
    for item in lst:
        try:
            item.video
        except Video.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        else:
            yield item

cleaned_list = clean(dirty_list)
```

Comment: Does this return a list or an iterator? Do you need `[x for x in clean(dirty_list)]` or not?

Comment: @LondonRob: In the answer `cleaned_list` will be an iterator. To get a list you can simplify your code to `list(clean(dirty_list))`.

Answer (score 4):

Python:

```
cleaned_list = filter(lambda x: hasattr(x, 'video'), dirty_list)
```

Django:
You could do the following if dirty_list is a queryset

```
cleaned_list = dirty_list.filter(video__isnull=False)
```